# Unable to connect to Excel using PHP ODBC connection (error IM002)

Tags: php, excel, odbc

I am getting error IM002 when trying to connect.

What is wrong with the script?

The file is not in the server, but on another machine. Server is Linux/Apache. Machine on which Excel file resides is a Windows machine.

```
$excelFile = realpath('\\10.40.64.100\$prntouts$\persmast.xls');
$excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
if ($connection){
 echo "Success";}
else{echo "Fail".odbc_error();}
```

Comment: Show us the result of [odbc_errormsg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php).

Comment: unsure why you are using a fixed IP rather than a name, clearly this 10.x.x.x will only work for local network but I presume that is fine with you. Can you explain what you have done to debug this - will it connect to another file on the same machine, is the same Excel driver version on the other machine, does this code work on a test machine etc.